# PyQt - Link background-color to a string

Tags: string, loops, colors, background

Hello I am creating a button grid through loops and trying to apply different colors to them.
My code is as such :

```
# Set Colors
colornumber = 24
color = ["red", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "white", "red", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "red", "red"]

# Set Lists
z = []
w = []
self.button = {}

# Set Loops
for i in range(4):
    for j in range (4):
        z.append(i)
        w.append(j)

for (a, b, c) in izip_longest (z, w, color):


                # Keep Buttons Reference
                self.button[(a, b)] = QtWidgets.QPushButton() 
                self.button[(a, b)].setStyleSheet("background-color: (%s %(c))")
                
                # Add to the Layout
                self.grid.addWidget(self.button[(a, b)], a, b)
```

So, a and b print position values and c iterates my list of color properly.

Now I'm trying to set colors on button with setStyleSheet but can't make it work.
As you can see in the code I tried to call them via `%s` but it does not work, probably because of the apostrophes around ? Is there a work around ?

Thank you!

Comment: i am not PyQt expert , but why don't you use ```f"background-color: {c}"``` ?

Comment: Hey I tried it this way ```d = 'red'
self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: {d}")``` but it does not seem to fetch the corresponding data either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working :) The `%s` but the second one that fetches the data needed to be outside the apostrophes..

```
                self.button[(a, b)].setStyleSheet("background-color: %s ;" %c)
```